# How to bring app from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, datetime, timer

How to hit method after some delay of time ( it's Min, hour, day ). And bring app from background to foreground even app is locked or another app is running. For e.g. Incoming call. Please help me to how implement

Comment: It isn’t possible.

Comment: For incoming calls your app should use CallKit

Comment: @ lorem ipsum, Paulw11, Thanks for answer. Is there any way only bring app background to foreground after some time if another app is running? By the way i am not implementing calling functionality. It is like alarm type popup i want show after some delay.

Comment: No apple wouldn’t allow it, it needs a user action via notifications, a deep link, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically bring an app to foreground on iOS. All you can do is schedule a [User Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) for a specific time and hope the user sees it (hasn't disabled your notifications) and taps it to bring your app to foreground.

See the Apple documentation and read some tutorials; that topic is way too complex for a single answer here.

You mention an "incoming call". So you might also want to look into [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) which may provide what you need.